# Use JClouds to talk to non AWS cloud with S3 API

Tags: amazon-s3, jclouds

I'm trying to use JClouds to talk to an OpenStack / swift storage cloud installation that only exposes a S3 API (it does not support the swift / rackspace API).

I tried:

```
Properties overrides = new Properties();
overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_ENDPOINT, CLOUD_SERVIE_ENDPOINT);

// get a context with nova that offers the portable ComputeService api
BlobStoreContext context = new BlobStoreContextFactory().createContext("aws-s3", ident,
    password, ImmutableSet.<Module> of(), overrides);
```

The server replies with an authentication error 403. Using the standard AWS sdk or python boto works fine, so it's not a server problem, but most likely incorrect use of jclouds.

Comment: Please close, turned out that the password I used was incorrect. Works with the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

**jclouds** in fact supports **swift**, so you don't need to do anything special.  I'd recommend using jclouds 1.3.1, and configure the dependency `org.jclouds.api/swift`

Then, you just need to enter you endpoint, identity, credential

```
Properties overrides = new Properties();
overrides.setProperty("swift.endpoint", "http://1.1.1.1:8080/auth");

BlobStoreContext context = new BlobStoreContextFactory().createContext("swift", "XXXXXX:YYYYY", "password", ImmutableSet.<Module> of(), overrides);
```

Comment: JClouds does, but the swift installation I try to use does not.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you.  It is known to work on vBlob, for example.

```
import static org.jclouds.s3.reference.S3Constants.PROPERTY_S3_VIRTUAL_HOST_BUCKETS;
...

     Properties overrides = new Properties();
     overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_S3_VIRTUAL_HOST_BUCKETS, "false");

     BlobStore blobstore = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(new S3ApiMetadata()) // or "s3"
                                         .endpoint("http://host:port")
                                         .credentials(accessKey, secretKey)
                                         .overrides(overrides)
                                         .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class).getBlobStore();
```

If your clone doesn't accept s3 requests at the root url, you'll need to set another parameter accordingly.

```
import static org.jclouds.s3.reference.S3Constants.PROPERTY_S3_SERVICE_PATH;
...

     overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_S3_SERVICE_PATH, "/services/Walrus");
...
                                         .endpoint("http://host:port/services/Walrus")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turned out to be a user error (see my comment). Unfortunately I can't delete the question and the moderators seem to be too busy.